# Changing the order of a double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let there be a sum $\sum_{k \geq 1}^{}\sum_{j \geq 1}^{} d(F_{j,k})^p$ where $F_{j,k}$ are sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d$ is defined as the diameter of the sets.

Why can we say that we might change the order of that sum randomly and get the same value? Remark please that I know that  I might change the order of every sum whose limit is finite as long as the sum of absolute values of the summands converges. My question is more about the case whether we get for every sum with changed order $\infty$ if $\sum_{k \geq 1}^{}\sum_{j \geq 1}^{} d(F_{j,k})^p=\infty$.

Comment: Write down the values of $F_{j,k}$ in a table, your goal is to get the sum of all elements of that table, why do you think the order of summation should matter?

Comment: The question isn't clear to me. I take it that both summations are infinite? Does the inner summation converge? Where you say "change the order of that sum randomly", do you really mean "randomly", or "arbitrarily"? If indeed randomly, according to what distribution? And by "changing the order", do you mean exchanging the inner and outer sum, or changing the order of summation in one of them? If the latter, in which one?

Comment: Since all the diameters are positive, order changing won't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm no native speaker, so sometimes my use of vocabulary doesn't fit up to 100%, sorry. Yes I mean arbitrarily. I mean to change the order of summation of the whole sum in an arbitrary way. So the changed order does not need to correspond to the order I posted above. In addition I want to allow values equal to $\infty$ but started with finite values. We had years ago Riemanns series theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) and I weren't sure...

Comment: whether I might get the case to find a permutation of values so that I have a infinite double sum but the "changed" series might be finite.

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind, but as long as all the terms are positive, reordering won't make any difference.  If the sum is infinite, it will always be infinite.  If the sum is finite, it will always stay finite at the same value.

Comment: I was puzzled, now I see clearer thank you all.